# Awk command to fill in the gaps in dates list

Tags: bash, awk

I have a comma-separated list of hundreds of lines starting with dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD. These dates are mostly consecutive but there are some gaps.

I would like to have an `awk` command to find these gaps and add new lines, for every missing date, with the missing date reported in the first column. The desired output will then have consecutive dates.

I'm on a Mac, for what it's worth.

Comment: consider reviewing [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular ... sample input, the (correct) desired output, the code you've tried so far and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MacOS /usr/bin/awk can't do it without calling out to `date`, but use Homebrew to install GNU awk:

The `input` file

```
2020-02-23 a
2020-02-24 b
2020-02-26 c
2020-03-02 d
2020-03-03 e
```

The `date_filler` code

```
#!/usr/bin/env gawk -f
BEGIN {DAY = 86400}
{
    split($1, d, "-")
    time = mktime(d[1] " " d[2] " " d[3] " 0 0 0")
}
NR > 1 {
    while (prev + DAY < time) {
        prev += DAY
        print strftime("%Y-%m-%d", prev)
    }
}
{
    print
    prev = time
}
```

And

```
$ chmod u+x date_filler
$ ./date_filler input
2020-02-23 a
2020-02-24 b
2020-02-25
2020-02-26 c
2020-02-27
2020-02-28
2020-02-29
2020-03-01
2020-03-02 d
2020-03-03 e
```